# Change default option deleting files

Tags: pantheon-files

In the recent versions of Elementary os when you delete a file it shows you a message with the default option being `Cancel`, in past versions the default option was `Delete`. There is any way to change this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only changed in the source code I am afraid.  I assume the default action as changed in order to comply with the elementary HIG which states:

> . Destructive actions should not be focused by default to prevent accidental activation.